# Can't understand the README file of an extracted tar.gz file

Tags: java

The readme file of a file says:

```
RUNNING:
1. Extract the contents of this .tar.bz2 file.
2. Change to the 'azureus' directory where the files were extracted.
3. Start Azureus by running the script named 'azureus'; ex. "./azureus"

NOTE:
If you have the Java JRE installed somewhere unusual (or not in your PATH),
use the JAVA_PROGRAM_DIR option in the script.
```

But just running ./azureus does nothing.

Comment: Why are you installing it this way ? azureus is in the repositories, `sudo apt-get install azureus` . If you must, do you have JRE installed ?

Comment: What do you mean it "does nothing"? No messages at all?

Comment: I installed bitmate

Comment: Yes I installed JRE. It seems the JVM is 64 bit while the bitmate app is 32 bit. How to rectify this?

Comment: just install things from the software center and you don't have to worry about JRE versions and JVMs.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need to install azureus manually. You can install it through the software center, or on the command line using:

```
sudo apt-get install azureus
```

That will take care of any java dependencies or other setup automatically.

Comment: I installed bitmate actually. I will post the result of running ./azureus

:

Comment: Suitable java version found [java = 1.7.0_55]
Configuring environment...
Java exec found in PATH. Verifying...
Browser check failed with: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM